Turning a simple python text encoder into a .exe file for sharing with friends and family
I have this code that I wrote to simply encode and decode passwords, but I need to share with with friends and family with the modules/packages easily, what's the best way to do so.
My code:
import cryptocode
choice = input("What do you want to do, encrypt or decrypt?")
dead = False
while dead == False:
    if choice == "encrypt":
        password = input("What is you password?")
        encryptionkey = input("What is your encryption key?")
        encoded = cryptocode.encrypt(password, encryptionkey)
        print(encoded)
        choice = input("What do you want to do, encrypt or decrypt?")
    elif choice == "decrypt":
        password = input("What is you password?")
        decryptionkey = input("What is your decryption key?")
        decoded = cryptocode.decrypt(password, decryptionkey)
        print(decoded)
        choice = input("What do you want to do, encrypt or decrypt?")
    else:
        choice = input("What do you want to do, encrypt or decrypt?")

I have tried pyinstaller but when I try to run the .exe it just quickly pops up with a black box and disappears, keep in mind I need to be able to write my own text in there. I am expecting it to open a worded prompt asking if I want to encrypt or decrypt then the password then the encryption key.

